# Samba not showing any shares

Tags: linux, ubuntu, network-shares, samba

When I run `smbstatus --shares` I see no shares listed.

This is at the end of my `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
[Share]
   path = /var/www
   available = yes
   valid users = robert
   read only = no
   browsable = yes
   public = yes
   writable = yes
```

This is the result of `testparm`:

```
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Processing section "[homes]"
Processing section "[printers]"
Processing section "[Share]"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

# Global parameters
[global]
        workgroup = MYGROUP
        server string = Samba Server
        server role = standalone server
        log file = /usr/local/samba/var/log.%m
        max log size = 50
        dns proxy = No
        idmap config * : backend = tdb


[homes]
        comment = Home Directories
        read only = No
        browseable = No


[printers]
        comment = All Printers
        path = /usr/spool/samba
        printable = Yes
        browseable = No


[Share]
        path = /var/www
        valid users = robert
        read only = No
        guest ok = Yes
```

I have created the samba user `robert` with `smbpasswd -a robert` as well as restarted samba with `sudo service samba restart`.

**Edit:** This is the result of `smbclient -L 127.0.0.1 -U robert`:

```
Domain=[MYGROUP] OS=[Windows 6.1] Server=[Samba 4.3.11-Ubuntu]

        Sharename       Type      Comment
        ---------       ----      -------
        Share           Disk
        IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (Samba Server)
        robert          Disk      Home Directories
Domain=[MYGROUP] OS=[Windows 6.1] Server=[Samba 4.3.11-Ubuntu]

        Server               Comment
        ---------            -------
        SHARE                Samba Server

        Workgroup            Master
        ---------            -------
        MYGROUP              SHARE
```

Comment: Try: smbclient -L 127.0.0.1 -U robert

Comment: Can you add an explanation as to *why* OP should try that? :)

Comment: Well, I ran the command anyways. See the edit in the OP.

Comment: Samba defaults to user authentication, you have to declare a user to access shares.   smbstatus shows current connections. No connections, nothing to show.

Answer (score 1):

The command `smbstatus --shares` lists actual connections to your CIFS shares so if there is no SMB client connected, it will output nothing.

The command to see what your server is sharing is the following (please note that the password prompt is not shown because of `grep`, so you need to type the password after having typed ENTER) :

```
$ smbclient -L 127.0.0.1 -U myUserName | grep share
Domain=[MYGROUP] OS=[Windows 6.1] Server=[Samba 4.3.11-Ubuntu]
        share          Disk
        robert          Disk      Home Directories
```

BTW: If one is using ActiveDirectory to authenticate their users, the command `wbinfo --ping-dc` helps one to be sure your Linux is still connected to the AD.